# Automatically Add criteria on each Spring Jpa Repository call

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm writing a library that wraps the `JpaRepository` interface of `Spring Data Jpa` because I want to add the same criteria automatically to all `JpaRepository` DB calls (something like `and where t > something`).

For example `findById` function of `JpaRepository` under the hood will be translated to `find by id and where t > something`

Is it possible? and if so, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a hibernate `@Filter` or simply a `@Where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long time ago this was planned, but the team came to the conclusion that it really doesn't seem possible to do it properly. So No, the feature does not exist. See here for details: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-293

There is [Hibernates `@Where`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-where) and [`@Filter`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-filter) though.